make_parallel_group: Can it be used with thread pool 'post'?
I'd like to have a function that applies elements from input range to the handler in a parallel. A possible implementation is:
template <typename Ex, typename Handler, typename Range>
void for_each_parallel(Ex executor, Handler handler, Range const& input)
{
    if (std::atomic<size_t> left = size(input))
    {
        std::promise<void> p;
        auto f = p.get_future();
        
        for (auto& el: input)
        {
            post(executor, [&] {
                handler(el);
                if (--left == 0) p.set_value();
            });
        }
        f.get();
    }
}

Is it possible to implement it by using ranged form of make_parallel_group(wait_for_all(),...)? No matter how I tried, I'm getting compiler errors.

It would help if you showed your attempt

@sehe I am not even sure I am on the right track. Here it is: https://godbolt.org/z/KKGrf97z5

@sehe does it make sense?

Yeah your godbolt makes sense to me. I think the core problem is that post only posts "a handler", not an async task with completion. (The handler is the completion). You want an async initiation, so to speak, async_post. Let's say you implement an async_post like so:
auto async_post(auto executor, auto op, auto&& token) {
    return asio::async_compose<decltype(token), void()>(
        [executor, fn = std::move(op)](auto& self) mutable {
            asio::post(executor, [fn = std::move(fn), self = std::move(self)]() mutable {
                fn();
                std::move(self).complete();
            });
        },
        token, executor);
}

Now you can create deferred ops from it:
void for_each_parallel(auto ex, auto action, auto& input_range) {
    auto&& ops =
        input_range //
        | ranges::views::transform(
              [&](auto& elem) {                                                    //
                  return async_post(                                               //
                      ex, [&elem, &action]() { action(elem); }, asio::deferred); //
              });

Sadly Asio doesn't recognize that view as is_async_operation_range. Let's cop out for now and convert to a vector:
    using Op = std::decay_t<decltype(ops.front())>;
    std::vector<Op> vops(ops.begin(), ops.end());

Now your original group does work:
    namespace X = asio::experimental;
    auto grp    = X::make_parallel_group(vops);

    std::move(grp).async_wait(                                    //
        X::wait_for_all(), [](std::vector<size_t> const& order) { //
            fmt::print("[{}]: finished in order {}\n", tid, order);
        });
}

See it Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/parallel_group.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

static std::atomic_int tid_gen = 0;
thread_local int const tid     = ++tid_gen;

auto async_post(auto executor, auto op, auto&& token) {
    return asio::async_compose<decltype(token), void()>(
        [executor, fn = std::move(op)](auto& self) mutable {
            asio::post(executor, [fn = std::move(fn), self = std::move(self)]() mutable {
                fn();
                std::move(self).complete();
            });
        },
        token, executor);
}

void for_each_parallel(auto ex, auto action, auto& input_range) {
    auto&& ops =
        input_range //
        | ranges::views::transform(
              [&](auto& elem) {                                                    //
                  return async_post(                                               //
                      ex, [&elem, &action]() { action(elem); }, asio::deferred); //
              });
    using Op = std::decay_t<decltype(ops.front())>;
    std::vector<Op> vops(ops.begin(), ops.end());

    namespace X = asio::experimental;
    auto grp    = X::make_parallel_group(vops);

    std::move(grp).async_wait(                                    //
        X::wait_for_all(), [](std::vector<size_t> const& order) { //
            fmt::print("[{}]: finished in order {}\n", tid, order);
        });
}

int main() {
    fmt::print("[{}]: main\n", tid);
    asio::thread_pool tp(3);

    std::vector input = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for_each_parallel(
        tp.get_executor(),                                 //
        [](int i) { fmt::print("[{}]: i={}\n", tid, i); }, //
        input);

    fmt::print("[{}]: done\n", tid);

    tp.join();
}

Printing, locally:


Updated range-v3 on coliru, so now output is present online: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed7f04c0daa3948f

Thank you for your time. Sadly, I still have a hard time to understand how to use async_compose properly. I slightly modified your example. Now for_each_parallel have additional completion token argument that is called when all tasks are complete. I tried to compose it with some predefined handler inside for_each_parallel, but still do not understand how to do it properly, lines 49-56. Could you provide some hint? https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27a41207aa0c0b12

Ah. So you want to both post parallel jobs and await them instead of the lambda you had. I'll show you what I think you wanted to do with async_compose (but you had it inside-out) as well as a much simpler approach which just uses the parallel group as a defacto composed operation: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0710278b8dbbd97
